# Best way to handle configuration in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Right now I have a service that runs and is injected into almost every single controller that provides a different API version string and URL string for requests based on $location's information as to whether the app runs on localhost or the website URL. Can something be set up to do something like this instead?

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(['$location', function($location) {
    // create app constants here and provide them globally somehow without requiring injection
    // something like constants.api, module.constants.api, or pretty much anything
    // else that exposes the keys set here in a developer-friendly way.
}]);
```

I am aware that `$location` isn't available in `.config`, so the above method won't completely work, but it's just food for thought.

I'm also open to any other suggestions on how to do all the configuration in AngularJS, because I haven't really found a good, clean way to specify app constants without having to use [insert build tool here] and create lots of constants and clutter my DI. I don't think AngularJS was intended to create such cluttered dependency management, but if I'm wrong, someone please correct me and explain a good way to set up better dependency management.

Comment: read about [provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

Comment: That still means I'll need to add that as a dependency for almost every controller I have, right? A provider would be no different in that case compared to the service that I currently inject. Please let me know if I'm missing something about providers and configuration, because I'm not too familiar with that.